Как использовать прокси с pyppeteer в python?
Я использую библиотеку pyppeteer в python для парсинга. Устанавливаю прокси следующим образом:
browser = await launch(headless=False,
                                   args=[
                                       f'--proxy-server=http://{self.proxy_list[self.rot]}'
                                       '--proxy-auth=***:***'
                                       '--no-sandbox'
                                       '--incognito'
                                   ])

Попробовал в таком браузере зайти на сайты, которые показывают ip, так они выдают мой реальный ip. Это же не так должно работать или я ошибаюсь?
Пробовал убирать пароль, так выдает ошибку:
net::ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES at

Поэтому раньше думал, что все работает, а теперь сомневаюсь.

Я разобрался. Так все работает.
browser = await launch(headless=self.hdls,
                               args=[
                                   f'--proxy-server=http://{self.proxy_list[self.rot]}'
                               ])
page = await browser.newPage()
await page.authenticate({"username": "***",
                         "password": "***"})

